# PHPExcel Add new rows without override existing info

Tags: addition, phpexcel, rows

Is possible add new rows in the middle of this sheet?

[image]

...without affect or overwrite the information at the bottom of the document?

I know that is possible create the bottom info manually, but I have to upload this Excel each month (with different header) and set the start row.

I've tried copy the last rows but **duplicateStyle** doesn't copy borders and backgrounds

```
# library
        $this->load->library('excel');
        $path = './assets/files/uploads/form.xls';      

        $excel  = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load( $path );
        $excel->setActiveSheetIndex(1);
        $row    = 10;
        $total  = 25;

        if( $total >= 20 )
        {           
            $cellValues = $excel->getActiveSheet()->rangeToArray( 'A30:L32' );
            $excel->getActiveSheet()->fromArray( $cellValues, null, 'A33' );
            $excel->getActiveSheet()->duplicateStyle( $excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle( 'A30:L30'), 'A32:L32' );
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a Worksheet method called `insertNewRowBefore()` (and a corresponding method for columns called `insertNewColumnBefore()`) that do this.

```
$excel->getActiveSheet()->insertNewRowBefore(10, 5);
```

will insert 5 new rows into the active worksheet, before row 10... effectively, it pushes row 10 down to row 15, row 11 down to row 16, row 12 down to row 17, etc; adjusting formulae and other cell references accordingly.

Likewise

```
$excel->getActiveSheet()->insertNewColumnBefore('B');
```

will insert a single new column (the default for both `insertNewRowBefore()` and `insertNewColumnBefore()` is a single row or a single column) before column `B`.

In the [examples folder](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/tree/1.8/Examples), `05featuredemo.php` and `30template.php` demonstrate the use of these methods

---

And

```
$excel->getActiveSheet()->duplicateStyle(
    $excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A30'),
    'A31:A100'
);
```

should copy all style elements (including borders and background) from a ***single*** cell to range of cells; but it won't copy different styles from a range of cells to a new range of cells.